# How do you call an AngularJS $scope.Function from href?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The following works to call a function ActiveChange(variable) from a

```
a(href="javascript: ActiveChange('topStories');") Top Stories
```

But if the function is defined as an AngularJS $scope function such as

```
function activeController ($scope) {    
    $scope.topStories='active';
    $scope.mostRecent='lucky';
    $scope.ActiveChange =   function (activeTab) {
        if(activeTab=='topStories'){
            var x=document.getElementById("someinput");
            x.value='happy to be alive';
            $scope.topStories='active';
            $scope.mostRecent='';
        }
        else {      
            alert('else');
            $scope.topStories='happy';
            $scope.mostRecent='active';
        }
    }
}
```

How do you call $scope.ActiveChange =  function (activeTab) from the  ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [ngClick](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick)?

Comment: yes, albeit not a very good reason. (lack of knowledge) Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: did I see DOM references in your controller? .... shame on you :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use `ngClick` like @Mike says. I don't see the reason to use angular in `href` .

Something like:

```
<a href="" ng-click="ActiveChange('topStories');">Top Stories</a>
```

Or leave it empty:

```
<a href ng-click="ActiveChange('topStories');">Top Stories</a>
```

Comment: The `href` value should be `javascript:void(0);` or be left empty - otherwise the browser will scroll the page up to the top. Returning false from the `ng-click` expression won't prevent it from happening (and I guess that's correct, since it'd be odd if a method of the scope had to be aware of the context it's getting called)

Comment: could also set the href equal to "javascript:angular.noop();" instead of "#" or "void(0)"